# What is workflow of Intune login token

Tags: ios, intune

I have integrated Intune SDK in my iOS application. When user share file from Outlook(Intune configured) to my app, my app shows Microsoft login screen to end user.

What happens after Microsoft login, internally with Intune?

How Intune SDK uses token generated in my application for MS login?

Is generated token, only for my application or Intune SDK shares internally with other application (outlook,Company portal, other developer Intune integrated app, etc) too?